# How to render different dropdown list dynamically based on selected option in first dropdown in React Js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I don't know where I am making mistake but I have tried all related videos and article but still not able to render dropdown list dynamically based on selected option in first dropdown.
there are two dropdown first one has some option so I want to change or render different option list in second dropdown whenever user change or select any option in first dropdown.
I don't know where I am making mistake. I using object array based data component as options data for second dropdown. where i change or select in first dropdown it got white screen.

**Option.js**

```
const Options = {

"Invoice Related" : ["buy","sell","hold"], 
"Payment Related" : ["recieved","cancelled","rejected","blocked"]
}

export default Options;
```

**Queryform.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Options from './FormOptions';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Queryform = () => {

const [dynamicOptions, setdynamicOptions] = useState([])

const selectedInput = (e) => {
  const input = e.target.value;
  console.log(input)
  console.log(Options)
  setdynamicOptions(Options[input])
}
 return (
  <div>
      <select className="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example"
          onChange={selectedInput}>
          <option selected>Category</option>
          <option value="Invoice Related">Invoice Related</option>
          <option value="Payment Related">Payment Related</option>
          <option value="Tax Related">Tax Related</option>
          <option value="Password Related">Password Related</option>
          <option value="Browser /Content/ Technical Related">Browser /Content/ Technical Related</option>
          <option value="MEDIANAMA Reports Related">MEDIANAMA Reports Related</option>
          <option value="Subscription Related">Subscription Related</option>
        </select>
  </div>
  <div>
   <select className="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
       <option selected>Options</option>
          {
            dynamicOptions.forEach((opt) => {
              <option value={opt}>{opt}</option>
            })
          }             
    </select>
 </div>
 )

export default Queryform;
```

Comment: There are some syntax errors and also an error where you are doing `dynamicOptions.forEach()` use `.map()` instead.

Comment: @IrfanullahJan thanks for the comment actually I tried map too but still not worked could you right the code here where i am making mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed some errors:

1. Added a parent [React Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) element to wrap multiple `<div />` elements, because this was giving me an error.
2. Replaced `dynamicOptions.forEach()` method with `dynamicOptions.map()`.
3. Only rendering second level select when `dynamicOptions` is defined.

Working implementation: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-rhodes-0tbtwd?file=/src/QueryForm.js

Please try the following:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const Options = {
  "Invoice Related": ["buy", "sell", "hold"],
  "Payment Related": ["recieved", "cancelled", "rejected", "blocked"]
};

const Queryform = () => {
  const [dynamicOptions, setdynamicOptions] = useState([]);

  const selectedInput = (e) => {
    const input = e.target.value;
    console.log(input);
    console.log(Options);
    setdynamicOptions(Options[input]);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <select
          className="form-select form-select-sm"
          aria-label=".form-select-sm example"
          onChange={selectedInput}
        >
          <option selected>Category</option>
          <option value="Invoice Related">Invoice Related</option>
          <option value="Payment Related">Payment Related</option>
          <option value="Tax Related">Tax Related</option>
          <option value="Password Related">Password Related</option>
          <option value="Browser /Content/ Technical Related">
            Browser /Content/ Technical Related
          </option>
          <option value="MEDIANAMA Reports Related">
            MEDIANAMA Reports Related
          </option>
          <option value="Subscription Related">Subscription Related</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        {dynamicOptions && (
          <select
            className="form-select form-select-sm"
            aria-label=".form-select-sm example"
          >
            <option selected>Options</option>
            {dynamicOptions.map((opt) => (
              <option value={opt}>{opt}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Queryform;
```

Comment: I have tried your code but still white screen and not working also why did you use ? sign before map i tried with this or without this too not worked

Comment: Oh, I needed that because `dynamicOptions` isn't always defined, now that I have a check for that before the second select, we don't need `?.` anymore. So, I have removed it. Please try the sandbox link I shared above.

Comment: your sendbox link working fine there but its not working in my code can I send you my project code in sendbox to you could you go through it and let me why its not working ?